# Update base table column, using a secondary table where we will have hierarchy for running the updates

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update

We have a base Table (say employees table) and a secondary table which has two things mainly
1) Hierarchy (0-10) to consider while updating base table
2) against each hierarchy there is another column called "COLS"
in this column we have values like 'EMPLOYEE_ID = 100', 
'HIRE_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-90 AND SYSDATE'

we need to update the base table field "VALS" by running through the hierarchy in secondary table and pick the columns in "COLS" column and update accordingly

I tried to play around with collections to get all column names and values
'EMPLOYEE_ID = 100' as FIELD = EMPLOYEE_ID and VALS = 100
for all the values in "COLS" COLUMN of secondary table

`````
DECLARE 
TYPE scio_r IS RECORD (cols VARCHAR2(40), valus NUMBER, HIER NUMBER);
TYPE scio_a IS TABLE OF scio_r;
nt_scio scio_a := scio_a();
COL VARCHAR2(40);
BEGIN
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(cols,'\S+') field,
     REGEXP_SUBSTR(cols,'[[:digit:]]+') vals,
     HIERARCHY
BULK COLLECT INTO nt_scio     
FROM temp_table ;
FOR x IN nt_Scio.FIRST..nt_Scio.LAST LOOP 
col := CASE WHEN x = nt_scio(x).hier THEN nt_scio(x).cols END;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(col);
/*DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nt_scio(x).cols);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nt_scio(x).valus);*/
END LOOP;
END;
/
````enter image description here[enter image description here][1]


[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/51pm3.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGIhD.jpg
`````

Comment: *"and pick the columns in COMMENT column and update accordingly"* - Update what? Or do you mean you want to update the column to that value?, if so which row has to be updated? Moreover, any reason why you are using this horrible table design?

Comment: I didn't understand _"we need to update the base table field by running through the hierarchy in  secondary table and pick the columns in COMMENT column and update accordingly"_, what will be search criteria and what will be new value and where is `COMMENT` column ?

Comment: Edited correct column names here please check now